# Installing Debian 7.6.0 on Lenovo Y50

Tags: linux, partitioning, debian, grub

I was trying to install Debian on my new laptop: a Lenovo Y50 64bit running Windows 8. I got together with a friend and installed Debian in his computer first and had no problems. However I've tried to install Debian several times using the AMD64 KDE and netinst versions and accomplished nothing.

First try: installed the KDE version. Grub would let me choose which operating system I wanted, but when I selected Debian it would only load the command line.

Second try: Reinstalled but this time with the netinst version. I only got a black screen where I could type but nothing else.

Third Try. Tried the netinst again. This time after making the partitions I got a message that said that no EFI partition was found. I ignored the message and this time it wouldn't even load Grub. only a command like interface with grub rescue or something.

Not once did I get an error during the installation. What am I doing wrong?

I assume the problem is I need to make an EFI partition or something like that. So why is it that during the first installations I didn't ask me for that. And if that is indeed the problem, How can I solve it?

---

Update

So the installation failed again... as predicted. Here you can find the Disk Management picture.  http://postimg.org/image/433cpfkjz/

Please somebody help me. I keep getting the grub rescue thing. secure boot is disabled and legacy support is set first.

Comment: Enter UEFI configuration (aka BIOS, but it's not a correct name because UEFIs replaced BIOSes) and disable CSM and secure boot. Then reinstall.

Comment: secure boot is disabled. what is CSM?

Comment: [CSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Compatibility_Support_Module). Are you installing Debian to replace Windows or to have them both? In the former case, are you going to ever return to Windows?

Comment: I would like to dual boot. especially since I am just a beginner I would still like to keep Windows and use it constantly.

Comment: If I understand the CSM correctly. I should change the boot mode from UEFI to Legacy support?

Comment: Disable legacy support for now. EFI partition is a partition that UEFI scans to find what OSes or OS loaders are bootable. If no EFI partition was found, then Windows is already quite broken. I don't know what exactly happened that broke it. For now I'd try to restore Windows and your files. If you have backups then try to restore from recovery partition and then restore your files. Laptop manual should have some details, actual steps differ between laptop models.

Comment: So I broke my computer and I need to restore windows???=S

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you can't boot Windows right now - so it's broken. If the damage wasn't too big then there may be another way, but it's more tricky. Full wipe and recovery is easier.

Comment: I can boot windows if I enter the boot menu and ask it to boot Windows that time

Comment: That's better, no need to recover then. Sorry, I don't have time to help you with installing Debian right now. A screenshot of Windows' *Disk Management* (Win+R, type `diskmgmt.msc`) may be helpful for others. (you don't have enough rep to post images so post a link, we'll embed it later)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I switched to boot from legacy mode first. I'm trying to re-install having done that. I still get the same no EFI partition found. It will probably fail again. As soon as it finishes installing i'll post the link to the picture.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16572/discussion-between-girauder-and-gronostaj).

Answer (score 0):

I did the same,  first,  change to legacy bios boot, second wipe the HDD and then convert from GPT to MBR (using @ctive partition manager part of active boot disk) then install win7 and Debian 7.6 as usual.

Comment: Now,  the problem are the drivers,  the wired LAN works and the video but without hardware acceleration...